# Javascript Adding variable to code

Tags: javascript

This might be a really simple issue but I cannot spot the problem.

I have this code:

```
output += '<li><a href="#"><img src="'+value.thumbnail_url+'" /><h3>'+value.title+'</h3>'+value.body+'</a></li>';
```

I need to add this code after the href="#"

and replace the url string with this: value.media_url

I've come up with:

```
output += '<li><a href="#" onclick="window.plugins.childBrowser.showWebPage('+value.media_url+');"><img src="'+value.thumbnail_url+'" /><h3>'+value.title+'</h3>'+value.body+'</a></li>';
```

but there seems to be a syntax issue with the above as the link is not working.

The broken code is somewhere here: `onclick="window.plugins.childBrowser.showWebPage('+value.media_url+');"` as the rest works fine.

I could go even further ... here:

```
('+value.media_url+')
```

Can anyone see the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replacing `onclick="window.plugins.childBrowser.showWebPage('+value.media_url+');"`  with `onclick="window.plugins.childBrowser.showWebPage('"+value.media_url+"');"` will fix it

Comment: Very strange...I replaced it with this: onclick="window.plugins.childBrowser.showWebPage('"+value.media_url+"');"  ... and the page show a ); in the top corner for some reason

Comment: It's a sadface at this answer's level of fail.

Answer (score 2):

The resulting string is:

```
window.plugins.childBrowser.showWebPage(my/url/to/file.png)
```

As you can see, it's missing quotes around the string. Since it's in an attribute, you need this:

```
... onclick="window.plu.....WebPage(&quot;'+value.media_url+'&quot;)" ...
```

Comment: Tried it but I get the actual &quot; as a string

Comment: If you're looking at the HTML source, it's supposed to be like that. The browser will interpret it as quotes and the script should work fine.